# Objective-C NSCoding and Read-only

Tags: objective-c

Objective C Read-only

I want to change my NSCoding property to read-only. 
For example, let’s set the readonly attribute for the lastName property on Person:

```
Person.h
@interface Person : NSObject
@property NSString *firstName;
@property (readonly) NSString *lastName;
@end
```

Assignment to readonly property

Okay, so outside code can’t set the property value, But when I tagged the lastName property with the readonly attribute by including (readonly) right after the @property declaration. but I still receive an error like this:

```
Person.m
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (void) changeLastName:(NSString *)newLastName;
{
  self.lastName = newLastName;
}
@end
```

Assignment to readonly property

What happens here? Can someone tells me why It doesn’t work. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redeclare it inside the class as readwrite

```
// Person.m
#import "Person.h"

@interface Person()
@property (readwrite) NSString *lastName;
@end

@implementation Person

-(void)changeLastName:(NSString *)newLastName;
{
  self.lastName = newLastName;
}

@end
```

Comment: +1: I prefer this answer to setting the ivar directly - it lets you override the setter if you have custom logic.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Edited to update. I agree strongly with you on this being the preferred solution over setting the iVar directly.

Comment: Wow... I've been using Objc for two years without knowing it was possible to redeclare a property like this...

Answer (score 1):

Properties don't distinguish between callers when you're trying to set a property. If you want to set a readonly property from inside its class, use

```
_lastName = newLastName
```

in your case to set the ivar directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a readonly property from inside its class, you can write the following code:

```
    _lastName = newLastName
```

You need to redeclare it inside the class as readwrite

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward.

If you want to set a readonly property from inside its class, use

```
  _lastName = newLastName
```

You need to redeclare it inside the class as readwrite